# In android, why service's oncreate() method invokes twice when the activity starts and destroys

Tags: android, android-activity, service

In main activity's `oncreate()`, the code is

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SampleService.class);
startService(intent);
```

In service's `oncreate()`, the code is

```
Toast.makeText(this, "oncreate", Toast.Length_Short).show();
```

When I start the activity, it shows "oncreate", but when I remove the activity from the recent application list, it also shows "oncreate", why?

Comment: Are you starting the service in `onResume` also ?

Comment: No, I have not. I think even add code in onResume, it only works when I return from the stopped state..

Comment: Would you send complete code please?